# How to automate multiple BLAST runs online?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I have the proteome of a bacteria in a FASTA file. Now, I want to run BLAST on individual protein with an antigen protein online. However, due to the large size of the proteome, running BLAST individually is cumbersome. What can I do to automate this process? I have some knowledge of Python but I am unable to make a pipeline to automate the process.

Comment: Start by looking at how to run a terminal command (ex: blastn) via python. Check out the "subprocess" package.

Comment: Do you know about BioPython? Here is a link to BioPython tutorial for running blast over internet: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec120

Answer (score 1):

Biotite, a package I am developing, has an NCBI BLAST interface: https://www.biotite-python.org/apidoc/biotite.application.blast.BlastWebApp.html

You could simply loop over all your sequences you would like to BLAST. However, the usage rules by the NCBI restrict each user to one BLAST job per 5 minutes, so it might run pretty long.

As I understand, you have just one protein reference sequence (the antigen), am I right? In this case it is probably easier to run a Smith-Waterman alignment for each query locally on your computer:
https://www.biotite-python.org/apidoc/biotite.sequence.align.align_optimal.html

Comment: Hi Padix, I was using biotite's NCBI blast interface. I noticed that if my blast query has more than one sequences, then the get_xml_response() functions returns the search result corresponding to only first sequence in the fasta file. Is there a workaround to get response for all the sequences ?

Comment: The current implementation of `BlastWebApp` uses only one query sequence per run. If you have multiple query sequences you would like to BLAST, you need to loop over the sequences.